# jQuery FullCalendar : When click created event disappers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I'm using the **fullcalendar** plugin with the resource view. (http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/).

I am trying to display a bootstrap form modal when clicking on an empty cell. (defaultView: 'resourceDay').

When I click on an empty cell modal opens and when I click **Save**, the new event will be added to the calendar. 
However there is a small bug.

If I click anywhere inside the **modal/browser window**, event **block** will disappear ( I can **click** on the calendar, this will create a coloured block on the empty cells temporally).

If I click **Save**, it will be re-added to the calendar.

For some reason if I put the FullCalendar's **renderEvent** inside a click function this bug occurs. 
how to fix this? Thanks!

(I have used the jquery UI dialog and tested, but it showed the same result to me)

**Call back JS function of the fullcalendar**

```
   select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {//select cell (empty)

                var title = 'Sample event';// event name

                $('#add_appt').modal();//open the modal

                $('#save_appt').click(function(e) {//click on the save button
                    //e.preventDefault();

                    if (title) {//Add the event
                        console.log("CONSOLE select event " + event + title + ", start " + start + ", end " + end + ", allDay " + allDay + ", resource " + resourceId);

                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay,
                                    resourceId: resourceId
                                }, true); // make the event "stick" as true

                    }
                    console.log("closing");
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

                    $('#add_appt').modal('hide');//close the modal
                });
    }
```

**HTML bootstrap modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_appt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Appointment</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<!--form -->
                <form id='appt_from' class="form-horizontal">
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Text Input</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Select Basic</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1">Option one</option>
                                <option value="2">Option two</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Textarea -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea">Text Area</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">                     
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
<!--/ from -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id='save_appt' type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I set the **unselectAuto** option to **false**. So when I click anywhere in the browser, event block will not disappear.

Only if I click **close** or **Save** button, I will call

```
 calendar.fullCalendar( 'unselect' );// var calendar = $('.container').fullcalendar();
```

Run this function inside **Close** and **Save** onClicks.

Hope this will help somebody.